# How to read an existing SOAP XML message?

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I am trying to read a [SOAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-serialize-an-object-as-a-soap-encoded-xml-stream) message such as the following one:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrjeffstevenson3/mmimproc/master/data/testdata/examcard/PHANTOM_QT1_SLU_20151230.ExamCard

This is an XML file which starts with:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<a1:ExamCard id="ref-1" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/Philips.PmsMR.ExamCards.ECModel/philips.pmsmr.examcards.ecmodel_cs">
```

How am I supposed to read such file ? How can I write the code for `rootClass` ? Pseudo code:

```
var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(rootClass));
using var myFileStream = new FileStream("PHANTOM_QT1_SLU_20151230.ExamCard", FileMode.Open);
var myObject = (rootClass)mySerializer.Deserialize(myFileStream);
```

Comment: By saying rootclas you mean Examcard ? from XML object ?

Comment: An XML this complicated should have a schema.  Then use the schema and the xsd.exe tool to create c# classes to use to deserialize.  The URL of the schema should also be in the xml file so people know where to find the schema.

Comment: I do not see any particular XSD being referenced from within the XML file itself: `cat PHANTOM_QT1_SLU_20151230.ExamCard | grep http | grep -v schemas.microsoft.com` -> returns nothing.

Comment: I suggest you contact this site and ask if a schema exists : https://www.usa.philips.com/healthcare/about/support-library

Comment: See github : https://github.com/mrjeffstevenson3/mmimproc?force_isolation=true and here : https://www.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/martinos/userInfo/data/MNE_register/